# How to resolve the duplicate symbol in 3rd party Framework in ios?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, google-plus

I am developing the Amazon login and Google Plus share in my project. I added the Amazon and Google plus framework in my project. when i try to build project it show "Duplicate symbol in GooglePlus and Amazon Framework" error.

Error Message

```
 duplicate symbol _kClientId in:
/Users/test/Amazon/Apps-SDK/iOS/LoginWithAmazon/LoginWithAmazon.framework/LoginWithAmazon(AIConstants.o)
/Users/test/GooglePlus/google-plus-ios-sdk-1.5.1/GooglePlus.framework/GooglePlus(GPPOzLogger.o)
 ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How To resolve this kind of error?

Answer (score 2):

All you can really do is contact Google and/or Amazon and tell them to fix their conflicting frameworks. It's kind of silly for both of them to use a global symbol name like `_kClientId` in their frameworks when the chances of a conflict happening with a name like that are extremely high. The names really should be something long like `_kGooglePlus_iOS_Framework_ClientId` and `_kAmazon_iOS_Framework_ClientId` for each respective framework to reduce the chances of symbol name collision.

Either do that or use a different framework or library for either Google Plus or Amazon, if you can. Or if you can't do that, use a HEX editor to manually change all references to the `_kClientId` symbol in one of the frameworks.

Comment: is there any other framework or any other way to implement the google+ sharing?

Comment: @harigharan That I do not know, no. You'll probably just have to Google it. Or Bing it – whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem some times ago. And finally I have figured out how to solve this.
As a client of library we can not avoid it, but we still have chance to deal with it.
My Answer include two parts, one to describe the problem, one to solve this problem as a client of framework(That means we have to solve this by our own not ask the developer of framework to workout this).

**1) How collision happened, and what does the link error mean?**

A framework is a folder actually, enter the framework you will find a lib file. Sometimes the lib file have a extension of *.a or just have no extension. The structure of a lib file looks like below:

```
libFoo.a  /  i386  /
                      hello.o
                      world.o
             arm64 /  
                      hello.o
                      world.o
```

In this case a libFoo.a is a fat library, that means it contains several architectures in it. The link error is telling you that you have two libraries that contain the same .o(symbols) file in the same architecture.

for example of your case:

```
duplicate symbol _kClientId in:
/Users/test/Amazon/Apps-SDK/iOS/LoginWithAmazon/LoginWithAmazon.framework/LoginWithAmazon(AIConstants.o)
/Users/test/GooglePlus/google-plus-ios-sdk-1.5.1/GooglePlus.framework/GooglePlus(GPPOzLogger.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This means in the two frameworks, you have duplicate .o files in the i386 architecture.

**2) How to solve the problem.**

We need some tools to solve this. Lucky, you should have those tools installed in your computer.
What we need to do is to open a framework and do some surgery to remove duplicate symbol and close it up.

I demonstrate the process here to remove the duplicate symbol AIConstants.o in LoginWithAmazon under i386 architecture:

```
lipo -info LoginWithAmazon //this is going to show us the architectures in the fat library
lipo LoginWithAmazon -thin i386 -output LoginWithAmazon-i386 //we extract the i386 architecture as xxx-i386 from fat library
//use the same command to extract every architecture from fat libraray as xxx-archname

ar -t LoginWithAmazon-i386 // list of symbols in this architecture, we should see AIConstants.o in it
ar -d LoginWithAmazon-i386 AIConstants.o // delete AIConstants.o from LoginWithAmazon-i386
//now work is done, we put everything back to the fat library

lipo LoginWithAmazon-i386 LoginWithAmazon-arm64 <every architecture you extracted from the fat library> -create -output LoginWithAmazon-new
ranlib -s LoginWithAmazon-new //sometime we need to rebuild the symbol table
//now you have done the work, use LoginWithAmazon-new to replace the old LoginWithAmazon, and try to compile your program again
```

**REF:**

http://blog.sigmapoint.pl/avoiding-dependency-collisions-in-ios-static-library-managed-by-cocoapods/

Comment: Nice description, however this does not work, because you also remove all other constants from AIConstants.o which will fail the linker for all other _k* references

Comment: I assume both version of AIConstants.o have the same content. If not so, you need framework source code to rebuild the whole thing which is unlikely to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this issue is not high priority for the login with amazon team.

As a temporary solution (believe it or not) you can use a text editor and replace all occurrences of "_kClientId" in the LoginWithAmazon binary with something else (like "_kClientIe").

See also my answer here:

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/18